# How do I loop through a string in R?

Tags: r, string, function, for-loop

I'm relatively new to R and trying to learn basic things like, in this case, looping through strings. 
What I need, is to loop through a string in R, like you would do in bash this way:

```
for i in `ls`; do mkdir TEST${i}; done
```

I need to define 5 functions each named submean1, ... , submean5. I tried to write it like this and I know there are errors but I can't get them because i'm n00b in R.

```
for (i in c(1,5)){
  submean$i = function(x){
    var = x-mean$i
    x = var
  }
}
```

I know it's something easy, but when you don't know where to start the best thing to do is to ask to people who already knows it.
Thanks a lot for the attention and eventually a solution.

Matteo

Comment: What you would like these functions doing? Remember it's better to define a list of functions rather than assigning function to names in the global envrionment ...

Comment: you can have a look at `?assign`.

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel I'd like these functions to substract the mean of the whole column (1 to 5) from every value of the column.

Comment: @Macspider To do that, you don't need to define such functions. Take a look at `help(scale)`.

Comment: a column of a data.frame... I guess that submean is a data.frame. Sorry but not stating explicitely what variable you are woking with is BAD :) Can you dput your data.frame? @Mamoun `assign` will work but this is also a BAD habit to drop things in the global env, good luck if you find normal to code like this in a functional langage ..:)

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel I found what I was looking for in the other question suggested by AshvinMeena. Thanks a lot anyway, you all have been useful. Have a nice day :)